# Attempt to read from field 'GlyphRun.color' on a null object reference

Tags: java, libgdx, truetype

I have been struggling to get fonts sort of working with libgdx and I finally did it.

But now it's throwing an exception, which I am not able to figure out.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout$GlyphRun.color' on a null object reference
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout.setText(GlyphLayout.java:141)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFontCache.addText(BitmapFontCache.java:505)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFontCache.addText(BitmapFontCache.java:487)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFontCache.setText(BitmapFontCache.java:438)
  at yt.agar.game.Screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:213)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

GlyphLayout.java:141:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.java#L141

I draw the font this way:

```
BitmapFont font = assetManager.get('arial-96.otf');
font.draw(spriteBatch, "sample text", 10, 10);
```

I generate the bitmapfont this way, using the `AssetManager`. I have tried a lot of different fonts, including truetype fonts.

```
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter font = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
font.fontFileName = "fonts/arial.otf";
font.fontParameters.color = Color.WHITE;
font.fontParameters.borderColor = Color.BLACK;
font.fontParameters.borderWidth = 3;
font.fontParameters.flip = true;
font.fontParameters.characters = FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS;
font.fontParameters.size = 96;

manager.load("arial-96.otf", BitmapFont.class, font);
```

I can't see that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in this way and it work fine for me :

```
public class TestGame extends Game {

    private AssetManager assetManager;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        assetManager=new AssetManager();
        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
        FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
        assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
        assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".otf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
        FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter size03Params = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        size03Params.fontFileName = "CHARLEMAGNESTD-BOLD.otf";
        size03Params.fontParameters.size = 96;
        assetManager.load("CHARLEMAGNESTD-BOLD.otf", BitmapFont.class, size03Params);

        assetManager.finishLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        spriteBatch.begin();

        if(assetManager.update()){
            BitmapFont font=assetManager.get("CHARLEMAGNESTD-BOLD.otf");
            font.draw(spriteBatch,"HEOOOW",100,100);
        }

        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        assetManager.dispose();
    }
}
```